# how can i remove a meta viewport on a theme file editor on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, responsiveness

How do I, remove meta viewport on Woodmart theme on Wordpress? because i don't want the responsive view on mobile i want the mobile view to be like desktop view and i cant find the meta viewport on the theme file editor this is what i find

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
```

in the header.php file, please help me?

i tried several ways by adding a javascript code i find online

```
function no_meta_viewport() {
  return false;
}
```

```
add_filter( 'ocean_meta_viewport', 'no_meta_viewport' );
, additional CSC code @media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .element-to-hide { 
    display: none !important; 
  } 
}
```

```
add_filter( 'ocean_meta_viewport', 'no_meta_viewport' );
, additional CSC code @media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .element-to-hide { 
    display: none !important; 
  } 
}
```

and lot more